# Android: IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, button, error-handling, logcat

I had a Java (Android) project on a computer, and when I run it on my device it worked very well.

After that I had to move that project onto another computer: same files, same stuff, anything modified. But now, while it's running I get this error: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"

The error come out when I press a button which calls an onClick method. If I dont' press that button everything goes well.

This is my LogCat

```
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    ... 11 more
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at iv.AppInditta.DbWorker.NewServerGetActivityTypes(DbWorker.java:3076)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    at iv.AppInditta.InDitta.faseuno(InDitta.java:641)
06-11 17:03:26.881: E/AndroidRuntime(15278):    ... 14 more`
```

Does anyone knows how to resolve this runtime error? It couldn't be a code error, I'm quite sure, because the same code on the previous computer works well...

Comment: I think your actual problem is the `NoClassDefFoundError` at DbWorker.java line 3076.

Comment: How did you add the library to your project path?

Comment: Right click on the Project main folder > Build Path > add external Archives...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
```

So my guess would be that you are missing the gson-library. Alternatively if you are working in Eclipse try to do a "Clean" on the project (Project -> Clean)

Comment: I just checked out, and the gson-library (gson-2.2.1.jar) is included in the Referenced Libraries, so the mistake couldn't be that. I tried to clean the project but the Error still remains. I tried to replace all the external jar libraries but without changes...I'm very confused!

Answer (score 0):

After a long searching I checked out the solution on a forum,

the problem is given by a reference to a library that I had (in my case it was gson) which was uncorrect.
I added the library to my project in a wrong way.
The procedure I used for implement a library in my project was:

1. Right click on the project in Eclipse
2. Build Path > Configure Build Path...
3. In the Libraries section click on Add External JARs...
4. Browse in the computer and find out the library I wanted to import, click OK and import it.

BUT THIS PROCEDURE IS UNCORRECT!!!!

For adding a library and making it available (and working) for the project **THE CORRECT PROCEDURE IS**:

1. Create a new folder named "libs" in your Eclipse/Android workspace project (you can do it in Windows Explorer if you're using Windows OS).
2. In Eclipse, right-click on the project and choose "refresh", this will refresh your project and add the "libs" folder
3. Right-click on the "libs" folder, choose Import > General > File System. Click NEXT and then browse in your pc to find the parent folder of the library you want to add (N.B. select the parent folder of the library, not the library.jar) and then click OK
4. Click the directory name of the library (which is displayed in the left panel) -not the checkbox-
5. On the right panel will be displayed the list of JAR files in that folder, select the checkbox of the one you want to install and click FINISH (this operation will add the library to your project, now you have to make it available for the project code)
6. Right-click on your project, choose Build Path > Configure Build Path...
7. In the libraries tab click in Add JARs..., browse your project and
   finr the library in your libs folder, add it.

Now the library is available and working for your project.

These steps worked for me, if you'll have the same problem I hope they'll work even for you.

Bye ;)